# What was Ash trying to do with the magazine?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-1979

In the movie *Alien*, Ash

> turns out to be an android. At one point, he freaks out, rolls up a magazine, and stuffs it into Ripley's mouth.

What in the world was he trying to do?

Comment: Kill her, perhaps? I assume he was confused/malfunctioning/not programmed for killing.

Comment: @TLP So they should have sent MODOK on the mission!

Comment: She was malnourished, and the stupid robot thought magazines were food.

Comment: Sigourney Weaver WAS malnourished in that flick.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ash is trying to kill Ripley, but the way he's doing it suggests some sort of sexual overtone that is seen in the movie Alien.

The movie Alien has a lot of [sexual overtones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_%28film%29#Analysis).

Comment: huh. What does it say about me that I never really noticed that?

Comment: I assumed it was more a reference to the facehuggers' method of impregnating a host (which is still a sexual overtone, just not the one I suspect you're implying).

Comment: @Xantec I didn't at first, but than one day I read the Wiki and...

Comment: As an added facet, it's apparently a porno mag that he uses. ;-)

Comment: @Raven13 Oh, I didn't know that. Is that really true?

Comment: @Eve - I read it in Ash's Wikipedia page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ash_%28Alien%29, last section), which gives a source, but I can't personally say for certain. It does add an extra facet of creepiness if true.

Comment: @Raven13 Sure does.

Comment: Agree on sexual overtones, but it makes little sense he was trying to kill her.   She can still breath through the magazine and ash doesn't cover ripley's nose.    I personally feel this was just a poorly conceived scene.   However if you read Ridley's Scott's explanation for the scene, he says it's that Ash is malfunctioning... he's a cyborg that can experience emotions in a HCI way to interact w/humans, but he doesn't process them all correctly.  Scott said that Ash experienced sexual feelings towards ripley and it screwed up his responses to her, resulting in the rape w/porno magazine.

Answer (score 17):

He's trying to suffocate her.

By rolling up the magazine, forcing it into her mouth, and then covering the other end with his hand, she would ideally die of asphyxiation without the suspicious marks that would be left if he simply used his hand, or choked her.

Comment: This really only works on mouth-breathers...

Comment: If the magazine goes far enough down it'll chock Ripley, not to mention that it's android doing this, with enough strength to achieve that.

Comment: Jamming a magazine down her throat would leave a different set of weird injuries for the coroner to find.  Unlike a banana the magazine's paper edges would likely result in extensive scraping/scratching on the way in.

Comment: True but who do you think would be doing the autopsy?  All Ash has to do is make sure there are no marks visable from a few feet away (where he can insist people move back to).

Comment: this explanation is pretty lacking- watch the scene and you'll notice ash doesn't cover her nose.   also- perhaps more importantly- he continues to use this method even after the crew has discovered him doing it.   so obviously it would neither have killed her nor would it have been a secret.     i think this was just a mistake on ridley scott's part.

Answer (score 5):

I thought he was trying to only knock her unconscious, as he still wants her body for er.. transport purposes. If he forced her to breath through a very small tube, like one formed by a magazine, he could knock her unconscious while keeping her alive on the minimal oxygen that she could breath through the small tube. The answers about killing her don't make sense to me. Didn't Ash still want to transport the Alien via Ripley at that point? Killing her would make that impossible.

Answer (score 4):

According to the film's director, Ash had deep-seated sexual urges toward Ripley but lacked physical capacity to do anything about it. When the situation required him to physically attack her he seized on this as an opportunity to use the porn magazine as a substitute penis.

> Ridley talked to Ian Holm about his character *"How do you feel about
> sexual drive?"*.  He said *"Great"*.
>
> Ridley continued ***"rather than just beating her up, isn't it more interesting that he
> actually has always wanted to, and here's his opportunity but he
> doesn't have that part, and therefore it's a magazine"***
>
> The Ridley later told Sigourney, *"come downstairs, it's gonna be
> great. Ash is gonna pick up this sex magazine and he's gonna stick it
> up your hooter"*
>
> Sigourney didn't know what hooter meant and even later thought it
> might be Cockney slang. She thought *"My hooter?"*
>
> When she got down stairs and they did the scene, she realised that actually it was up her mouth.
>
> <sub><sup>[Alien: The unravelling of Ash](http://alienexplorations.blogspot.co.uk/1979/10/unravelling-of-ash.html) (referencing "The Making of Alien")</sup></sub>

Comment: This is only explanation that is consistent with itself.  There is no world in which you can kill somebody with a magazine the way ash was using it.  He didn't even cover her nose, and he continued even after the crew tried to stop him.  It couldn't have been a serious attempt to kill, much less a secretive one as some others here have implied.

Answer (score -3):

He did that because he was not actually programmed to kill humans directly due to his behaviourial inhibitors but became confused as a result of his new 'orders' -or re-programming' if you will. After Ripley becomes a direct threat since she found the true nature of the company's intentions, Ash goes after her but not really understandting exactly how to dispatch her. Upon seeing the magazine he quickly concluded he could suffocate her with it.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to back this up?

Comment: It is clear that the androids in this story universe lack such rules, just like the replicants seem to kill without compunction.